# continuïty of more dimensional function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

for the past few day I've been studying analysis. More specific the topic of the continuïty of function from $\mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I was trying to solve the following problem, but got stuck with it. It goes as follows: Let $f:\mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}^p$. For every $u \in \mathbb{R}^p$ with $||u|| = 1$ we define the following function
$$g_u: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: t \rightarrow g_u(t) = f(a+tu)$$
The question is, if for every $u \in \mathbb{R}^p$ with $||u|| = 1$, $g_u$ is continuous in $t=0$ is $f$ then continuous in $a$? I think the answer is no, but I can not seem to find a counterexample. Trying to prove it also didn't work. But I think it is incorrect because out of the assumption one can not be sure that for every sequence in $\mathbb{R}^p$, which converges to $a$, $f$ of that sequence will converge to $f(a)$. Does anyone have a tip, any help would as always be grealty appreciated :))

Comment: Look for a counterexample with $p=2,a=0$. The hypothesis implies that $f$ is continuous along every straight-line path through $a$, but not necessarily along curved paths. Try thinking of a class of curved paths through $a$ and designing $f$ to be constant on each such path but different on different such paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually no. Consider the following standard counterexample:
$$p=2 \qquad a = (0,0) \qquad f(x;y)= \left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        1 & \text{if } y = x^2 & \text{and } x \neq 0 \\
        0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{array}
\right\}$$
Then you can easily notice that the corresponding $g_u(t)$ is continuous in $0$ for each $u \in R^2$, but $f$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$. In fact, $f(0,0)=0$, but, considering the sequence:
$$b_n = \left(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
We have:
$$b_n \to (0,0)$$
But:
$$f(b_n) = 1 \to 1$$

Comment: thank you very much!!